# How to stop and start Adobe Creative Cloud in Apple Terminal?

Tags: terminal, macros, terminal.app, adobe-creative-cloud

I've tried using

`osascript -e 'tell application "Creative Cloud" to quit`

but get the error message

`17:18: syntax error: Expected expression, property or key form, etc. but found unknown token. (-2741)
Wills-Air:~ WilliamSam1$`

Comment: for starters, try matching the quotes at both ends...

Comment: after edit, quotes still don't match... please edit to show the exact command line you entered

Answer (score 1):

It is loaded by default by:

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist
```

If you run:

```
launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist
```

That will disable it for your user.

To turn it back on:

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist
```

Source: **[How do I stop the Adobe Creative Cloud App from auto launching on Login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138941/how-do-i-stop-the-adobe-creative-cloud-app-from-auto-launching-on-login)**